# FluentValidation validator not being called

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, partial-classes, fluentvalidation

I have a MVC 3 site but am using the non-MVC FluentValidation dll.  I've created a validator class and in the constructor put all my RuleFors and then set an attribute on my model class thus

```
[FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(MyValidator))]
```

The problem is that the constructor on the validator class never gets called.  I think it might be because I am not using the MVC version of the dll, but then I could not get that version to work for me either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `Application_Start` make sure that you have initialized the custom fluent validation model validator provider otherwise nothing will happen:

```
FluentValidation.Mvc.FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
```

The `FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider` class is defined inside the `FluentValidation.Mvc` assembly. Please take a look at the documentation for [integrating FluentValidation into an ASP.NET MVC site](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation).

The validator will be triggered when you invoke a controller action taking a model decorated with the `[Validator]` attribute as argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Process(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Make sure to be using `FluentValidation.Mvc`, NOT `FluentValidation.Mvc.WebApi`as the provider exists in both. Caught me out.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason your validation might not be called is if you have more than one constructor.  I did this by accident and it was mystifying.  I am so used to having a service constructor just pass in required services from dependency injection, that I did this by mistake:

```
public MyValidator(IJsonService jsonService)
{
    _jsonService = jsonService;
}

public MyValidator()
{
    RuleFor(x => x.ProductTechnologyId).GreaterThan(0).NotEmpty();
}
```

Only one constructor can be called!  Oops!